# what is the best measuring strategy for openlayer 2

Tags: javascript, openlayers

Am using the following method for measuring but it is only accurate near the equator.

```
  measureControl.getCustomLength = function (evt, onlySum) {
    var idx = evt.geometry.components.length;

    if (idx < 2)
        return '';

    var geom = new OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString([
        evt.geometry.components[idx - 2],
        evt.geometry.components[idx - 1]
    ]);

    var lastLengthArr = this.getBestLength(geom);

    var str = '';

    if (idx > 2 || onlySum) {

        str += 'Total: ' + (evt.units === 'km' ? ConvertKmToOtherUnitsForMapLen(evt.measure, true, 3) : ConvertKmToOtherUnitsForMapLen(evt.measure / 1000, true, 3)) + '<br>';           
    }
    if (!onlySum) {
        str += 'Current segment: ' + (lastLengthArr[1] === 'km' ? ConvertKmToOtherUnitsForMapLen(lastLengthArr[0], true, 3) : ConvertKmToOtherUnitsForMapLen(lastLengthArr[0] / 1000, true, 3));           
    }

    return str;
}
```

Is there another better way to implement a measuring tool to give best results in any position on the map? Am using EPSG:4326 projection.

Comment: What are the results you expect?

Comment: I expect consistence results all over the map.

Answer (score 0):

OpenLayer has everything you need to measure: [ol.Sphere#getLength](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.Sphere.html#.getLength) takes a geometry and calculates it's size in meters.

Take a look at the [Measure Example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/measure.html), it shows how to use it.

```
const lineString = new ol.geom.LineString([[-1e7, 1e6], [-1e6, 3e6]]);
const meters = ol.Sphere.getLength(line);
```